# SSIS package: ForEach Container is picking undefined file from the source location

Tags: ssis

[image][image]My SSIS Package takes gpg file rather then text file i have puts file "*.txt" file in Files. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your ForEach container's properties, showing where you have put the `*.txt`.

Comment: Please see the image as i am geeting .gpg file but it should take only text file.

Comment: Check the XML code behind the for each loop. Maybe something has gone wrong over there because the For Each loop editor seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, documented behavior.   From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187670.aspx):

> Use wildcard characters (*) to specify the files to include in the
>   collection. For example, to include files with names that contain
>   “abc”, use the following filter: `*abc*`.
>
> When you specify a file name extension, the enumerator also returns
>   files that have the same extension with additional characters
>   appended. (This is the same behavior as that of the dir command in the
>   operating system, which also compares 8.3 file names for backward
>   compatibility.) This behavior of the enumerator could cause unexpected
>   results. For example, you want to enumerate only Excel 2003 files, and
>   you specify "*.xls". However, the enumerator will also return Excel
>   2007 files because those files have the extension, ".xlsx".
>
> You can use an expression to specify the files to include in a
>   collection, by expanding Expressions on the Collection page, selecting
>   the FileSpec property, and then clicking the ellipsis button (…) to
>   add the property expression. For more information about dynamically
>   selecting specified files, see SSIS–Dynamically set File Mask :
>   FileSpec

Try using `*txt` instead of `*.txt` so it doesn't treat "txt" as an extension and include files that end in ".txt.gpg"